# Returning values and data typs validation in python

Tags: python

How can I return (function polygon) not print all this x1 y1, x2 y2, ... values in tuples? Case of an errors of data typs float, how to use exceptions? I use Python 3.

```
import math
def polygon(num_of_edges, radius, startx, starty, turning_angle):
    turning_angle = 90 - turning_angle 
    first_angle = math.radians (turning_angle)
    i = 0
    while (i < num_of_edges):
        angle = 2*math.pi*(-i)/num_of_edges+first_angle 
        x = math.cos(angle)*radius+startx
        y = math.sin(angle)*radius+starty
        print ("x",i+1,"=",x) 
        print ("y",i+1,"=",y)
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to collect those points in a list, then return that list. You can also make your code somewhat shorter by using a `for` loop instead of `while`:

```
def polygon(num_of_edges, radius, startx, starty, turning_angle):
    turning_angle = 90 - turning_angle 
    first_angle = math.radians(turning_angle)
    points = []
    for i in range(num_of_edges):
        angle = 2*math.pi*(-i)/num_of_edges+first_angle 
        x = math.cos(angle)*radius+startx
        y = math.sin(angle)*radius+starty
        points.append((x, y))
    return points
```

Instead of collecting them in a list, you could also make your function a generator:

```
def polygon(num_of_edges, radius, startx, starty, turning_angle):
    turning_angle = 90 - turning_angle 
    first_angle = math.radians(turning_angle)
    for i in range(num_of_edges):
        angle = 2*math.pi*(-i)/num_of_edges+first_angle 
        x = math.cos(angle)*radius+startx
        y = math.sin(angle)*radius+starty
        yield (x, y)
```

Comment: First variant very good for me... How validate float data type for radius, startx, starty, turning_angle?

Comment: @ziile What do you mean? If you want to make sure those are `float` and not `int`, just add `radius = float(radius)` etc. at the top of the function.

Comment: How to use exceptions?

Comment: Perhaps try statement helpfull here?

Comment: @ziile Yes, _perhaps_ `try` is helpful, but I can't tell for sure, because my crystal ball is broken and I thus have no idea what you are doing with that `try`.